# Internet is insanely slow on home network only with one computer

Tags: wireless

I've got a really weird problem. I just switched from at&t to comcast. Since I switched modems I had to reconfigure my wireless network. I got it done no problem, but now on the computer I set up the network with I can barely connect to the internet. 
I can connect to other networks using this partition; I'm doing it right now using my Nexus 4 as a hotspot, which is connected to the home wifi.

I've also got a linux Mint computer on the network that works well. I've got another home theater computer and small windows 7 computer connected no problem. The only trouble is on my laptop running 12.04 LTS. Even in my Windows 7 partition on that same laptop I can connect no problem.

I've tried deleting the connection from my saved networks and trying to reconnect to it, but no dice. Any thoughts as to what might be causing the trouble?
I'm using an Asus K55VD.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,
So I finally got it working. I tried a few things, but what worked was reconfiguring the wireless router.

Answer (score 0):

Ah,.. just read the rest more carefully. If there are other connections to the LAN some may get priority, based on some earlier setting. Not many routers do this and I've only come across one in years of tinkering with them.

Might be worth checking to see if your router has this bizarre priority handling setup.

Comment: No, that can't be because the problem occurred before I connected anything else to the network. Thanks for the suggestion though!